# Vuex/quasar - mutate state from firebase 9 on boot

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I'm using quasar with firebase 9. I'm trying to set the state with actions during the boot of the project. I have data in firebase that I want to load only once and assign to an array in the Vuex state.
there might be a way in firebase 8 but I can't solve this problem in the newer version of firebase

```
    import { getData } from "src/firebase/config";

// load data from packages collection
export const loadPackages = async () => {
  const packages = await getData("packages");

    return packages;
}

// load data from menu collection
export const loadMenu = async () => {
  const packages = await getData("meals-menu");

    return packages;
}
```

I use the return of each function in the respective vue component but I want to use the return in mutating the vuex state.

any tips?

thank you

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

as a work around solution; try saving data from firebase into localstorage then set vuex state after localstorage is set

Answer (score 0):

firebase collection has event methods to allow exactly this

Look at this as starting point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_an_observer

Inside event handlers you have the 'realtime' changes/added/removed data

So you can change store